# Create charts from SQL query

Tags: apache-superset

I want to create a chart from a join sql query between 2 tables in superset.

for example , I go to SQL Lab and execute this query :

```
select film, count("film") from rental r, payment p where r.rental_id=p.rental_id group by("film") order by count("film") limit 20;
```

This returns me a result but how to insert in a chart?

How to create chart from SQL query ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In order to visualize the results from a query executed in SQL Lab, you first need to click on Explore (underneath the Results tab). 
Once you are in exploration mode, you can change the "Visualization Type", under "Datasource & Chart Type".